# The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I try to implement LinkedIn Authentication in my VS 2010 MVC3 application. I refer source

code in a blog website. But i found there is a error occurred in while building the code.

Please see this below image.

[image]

There is any reference needed in this 'T' object.

Please help.

**UPDATE QUESTION**

I update my question as per @StuartLC

[image]

Comment: Is that used to represent a type? For generics.

Comment: that's a generic placeholder ... the function should be present in a generic class where the generic placeholder is named T

Comment: You'll have to call it with the type parameter: `return Deserialize<Person>(response.Content);`

Comment: Thank you @p.s.w.g. I do this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change the method signature like so:

```
private T Deserialize<T>(string xmlContent)
```

Then, you'll explicitly need to provide the type parameter every time you call the method, because `T` cannot be inferred (e.g. from the parameters), i.e.

```
var widget = Deserialize<Widget>(someXmlString);
```

**Edit** As per @pswg's comment, you could also make the whole class generic, if this makes sense to do so. You then wouldn't need to specify the type parameter in on the `Deserialize` method, as it is now inherent in the class. You will however need to make the method more visible (e.g. `public`) if it is to be called outside of the class.

```
var widgetDeserializer = new MyDeserializerClass<Widget>();
var widget = widgetDeserializer.Deserialize(someXmlString);
```

Comment: Or possibly make the class generic, but +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the Type of the deserialized object...

```
private T Deserialize<T>(string xmlContent)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this

```
private T FuncName<T>(T param) where T : class
{
            return param;
}
```